# Why does my custom network Manager disable the main one

Tags: unity, multiplayer, software-engineering, matchmaking

Whenever I add a custom Network Manager to add functionality to and override it's functions, the main NetworkManager got disabled so I could not see the NetworkManager HUD or start matches. It there a way around that?

(EDIT)
[Thanks for the response]
It's not just the HUD that's the issue. The Networking is disabled entirely. Can I change this through a custom HUD?

Comment: What do you by " entirely " , for solution to work , you must add the derived NetworkManager and CustomHUD to an empty game object ,   then drag NetworkManager into HUD manager field , and its probably better to delete [RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkManager))] from the code below since we're providing our own manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Network Manager in Unity is implemented using singleton pattern , so you can't have two of them in the scene, naturally after implementing the inherited  Network Manager functionality , programmers tend to write a custom  HUD.

Here is a one:

```
#if ENABLE_UNET

namespace UnityEngine.Networking
{
[AddComponentMenu("Network/NetworkManagerHUD")]
[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkManager))]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public class NetworkManagerHUD : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NetworkManager manager;
    [SerializeField] public bool showGUI = true;
    [SerializeField] public int offsetX;
    [SerializeField] public int offsetY;

    // Runtime variable
    bool showServer = false;

    void Awake()
    {
        manager = GetComponent<NetworkManager>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!showGUI)
            return;

        if (!NetworkClient.active && !NetworkServer.active && manager.matchMaker == null)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                manager.StartServer();
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
            {
                manager.StartHost();
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                manager.StartClient();
            }
        }
        if (NetworkServer.active && NetworkClient.active)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
            {
                manager.StopHost();
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!showGUI)
            return;

        int xpos = 10 + offsetX;
        int ypos = 40 + offsetY;
        int spacing = 24;

        if (!NetworkClient.active && !NetworkServer.active && manager.matchMaker == null)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "LAN Host(H)"))
            {
                manager.StartHost();
            }
            ypos += spacing;

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 105, 20), "LAN Client(C)"))
            {
                manager.StartClient();
            }
            manager.networkAddress = GUI.TextField(new Rect(xpos + 100, ypos, 95, 20), manager.networkAddress);
            ypos += spacing;

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "LAN Server Only(S)"))
            {
                manager.StartServer();
            }
            ypos += spacing;
        }
        else
        {
            if (NetworkServer.active)
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 300, 20), "Server: port=" + manager.networkPort);
                ypos += spacing;
            }
            if (NetworkClient.active)
            {
                GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 300, 20), "Client: address=" + manager.networkAddress + " port=" + manager.networkPort);
                ypos += spacing;
            }
        }

        if (NetworkClient.active && !ClientScene.ready)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Client Ready"))
            {
                ClientScene.Ready(manager.client.connection);

                if (ClientScene.localPlayers.Count == 0)
                {
                    ClientScene.AddPlayer(0);
                }
            }
            ypos += spacing;
        }

        if (NetworkServer.active || NetworkClient.active)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Stop (X)"))
            {
                manager.StopHost();
            }
            ypos += spacing;
        }

        if (!NetworkServer.active && !NetworkClient.active)
        {
            ypos += 10;

            if (manager.matchMaker == null)
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Enable Match Maker (M)"))
                {
                    manager.StartMatchMaker();
                }
                ypos += spacing;
            }
            else
            {
                if (manager.matchInfo == null)
                {
                    if (manager.matches == null)
                    {
                        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Create Internet Match"))
                        {
                            manager.matchMaker.CreateMatch(manager.matchName, manager.matchSize, true, "", manager.OnMatchCreate);
                        }
                        ypos += spacing;

                        GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 100, 20), "Room Name:");
                        manager.matchName = GUI.TextField(new Rect(xpos+100, ypos, 100, 20), manager.matchName);
                        ypos += spacing;

                        ypos += 10;

                        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Find Internet Match"))
                        {
                            manager.matchMaker.ListMatches(0,20, "", manager.OnMatchList);
                        }
                        ypos += spacing;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var match in manager.matches)
                        {
                            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Join Match:" + match.name))
                            {
                                manager.matchName = match.name;
                                manager.matchSize = (uint)match.currentSize;
                                manager.matchMaker.JoinMatch(match.networkId, "", manager.OnMatchJoined);
                            }
                            ypos += spacing;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Change MM server"))
                {
                    showServer = !showServer;
                }
                if (showServer)
                {
                    ypos += spacing;
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 100, 20), "Local"))
                    {
                        manager.SetMatchHost("localhost", 1337, false);
                        showServer = false;
                    }
                    ypos += spacing;
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 100, 20), "Internet"))
                    {
                        manager.SetMatchHost("mm.unet.unity3d.com", 443, true);
                        showServer = false;
                    }
                    ypos += spacing;
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 100, 20), "Staging"))
                    {
                        manager.SetMatchHost("staging-mm.unet.unity3d.com", 443, true);
                        showServer = false;
                    }
                }

                ypos += spacing;

                GUI.Label(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 300, 20), "MM Uri: " + manager.matchMaker.baseUri);
                ypos += spacing;

                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(xpos, ypos, 200, 20), "Disable Match Maker"))
                {
                    manager.StopMatchMaker();
                }
                ypos += spacing;
            }
        }
    }
}
};
#endif //ENABLE_UNET
```